# How to check if the user is travelling or he is waiting in some unknown location based on lat long and duration in postgres

Tags: postgresql, geometry, postgresql-9.1

I have a table which is populated with user data
I want to calculate if user is traveling or he is waiting in some unknow location using postgres

I have calculated distance base on consecutive rows of column lat,long using st_distance also duration in sec based on  consecutive rows of column date_time NOW next :( im stuck or is there any alternative solution in postgres for it

```
 date_time | userid | dt_long | dt_lat | distance_mtr | duration_sec
 2019-10-18 10:03:00 |1| 77.3226415 |  28.428391 |0.0001804914679486078 |    0
 2019-10-18 10:04:00 |1| 77.3223706 | 28.4284229 |0.0002727717360762829 |   60
 2019-10-18 10:04:00 |1| 77.3234293 | 28.4286591 |0.0010847285973934345 |    0
 2019-10-18 10:05:00 |1| 77.3235954 | 28.4312008 | 0.002547121532238275 |   60
 2019-10-18 10:06:00 |1| 77.3232383 | 28.4339188 | 0.002741358132388037 |   60
 2019-10-18 10:07:00 |1| 77.3189726 | 28.4372124 | 0.005389248319574446 |   60
 2019-10-18 10:07:00 |1| 77.3199512 | 28.4337363 |0.0036112226696816577 |    0
 2019-10-18 10:08:00 |1| 77.3166132 | 28.4390238 | 0.006252991304168849 |   60
 2019-10-18 10:25:00 |1| 77.3121945 | 28.4417992 | 0.005218022120497835 | 1020
 2019-10-18 10:26:00 |1|  77.311836 | 28.4469267 |   0.0051400173637846 |   60
 2019-10-18 10:26:00 |1| 77.3122629 | 28.4443448 | 0.002616954569722247 |    0
 2019-10-18 14:59:00 |1| 77.3083439 | 28.4440584 | 0.003929451101613379 |16380
 2019-10-18 15:00:00 |1| 77.3091388 | 28.4335478 | 0.010540615654220696 |   60
 2019-10-18 15:01:00 |1| 77.3097761 | 28.4260216 | 0.007553134298422493 |   60
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Would you mind format your code and provide a [mcve]. Also could you list what you have tried so far.

Comment: Also take care to anonymize data including coordinates. What kind of distance are we considering? You also have a duplicate timestamp is it normal?

Comment: Timestamp is duplicate with respect to different lat long as per data been captured

Comment: OK, also consider other remarks as well. There is not enough information and effort shown to address your question.

Comment: Unrelated to your problem, but: Postgres 9.1 is [no longer supported](https://www.postgresql.org/support/versioning/)  you should plan an upgrade as soon as possible.